# Android accessibility service for gesture screen lock

Tags: android, accessibility, gesture

I'm looking at creating my gesture lock screen, which will be shown once screen is on.

It can not achieved using screen on\off broadcast receiver as they won't work if registered from manifest. And you can not keep service running all time.

My Service looks like.

```
public class CustomAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    // event.getSource(), findFocus(int), getWindows(), or getRootInActiveWindow().

    Toast.makeText(this, "onAccessibilityEvent" + event.getSource(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onInterrupt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onGesture" + gestureId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onGesture(gestureId);
}
```

}

Manifest file

```
<service
        android:name=".CustomAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/service_configuration" />
    </service>
```

And Service_configuration.xml as below.

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewAccessibilityFocused|typeViewAccessibilityFocusCleared"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:packageNames="com.xxxx.gesturelockscreen" />
```

I am stuck on it.

I know that we need to activate accessibility service (Gesture lock screen) and I am using below code to check if it is enabled.

```
 if (!isAccessibilityEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not Enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {
 //Good to go!
  }

public boolean isAccessibilityEnabled() {
    int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
    final String ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_NAME = "com.xxx.gesturelockscreen/com.xxx.gesturelockscreen.CustomAccessibilityService";
    boolean accessibilityFound = false;
    try {
        accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
        Log.d(TAG, "ACCESSIBILITY: " + accessibilityEnabled);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

    if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
        Log.d(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILIY IS ENABLED***: ");


        String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting: " + settingValue);
        if (settingValue != null) {
            TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter splitter = mStringColonSplitter;
            splitter.setString(settingValue);
            while (splitter.hasNext()) {
                String accessabilityService = splitter.next();
                Log.d(TAG, "Setting: " + accessabilityService);
                if (accessabilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE_NAME)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "We've found the correct setting - accessibility is switched on!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "***END***");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILIY IS DISABLED***");
    }
    return accessibilityFound;
}
```

Now I want when screen is on my custom accessibility service's need to be called.

Please help, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.